# how do i keep emacs server running when the current window is closed (x) on windows using emacsW32?

Tags: emacs, emacs23, emacsw32

I'm using [EmacsW32 (patched)](http://www.ourcomments.org/Emacs/EmacsW32.html) on windows.  Emacs is running in server mode so that subsequent calls to emacsclientw open files in the same server session.

I have **C-x C-c** mapped to make the current frame invisible and not kill the emacs server process.  I'd like clicking the window's **X** (close) button to also just hide the frame & not terminate the server process as it currently does.

Any ideas ?  Thanks!

Comment: May I ask how you "make the current frame invisible and not kill the emacs server process"?

Comment: Never mind, I found it... for reference, this works perfectly: http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2009/03/windows-and-daemons.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, I have a method of doing this.  There may be refinements possible, but this is a good starting place.

First, I setup a variable and advise the kill-emacs function

```
(defvar bnb/really-kill-emacs nil)
(defadvice kill-emacs (around bnb/really-exit activate)
    "Only kill emacs if the variable is true"
    (if bnb/really-kill-emacs
        ad-do-it)
      (bnb/exit))
```

The bnb/exit function just makes the frame invisible like what you have bound to **C-x C-c**.

I then have an additional function to properly exit emacs if that is ever necessary.  That will set the variable and call kill-emacs as follows.

```
(defun bnb/really-kill-emacs ()
    (interactive)
    (setq bnb/really-kill-emacs t)
    (kill-emacs))
```

Comment: Thanks!  Most of the time I'll be using C-x C-c, but found myself X'ing out the window recently & the server restarts were driving me crazy :-)

Comment: +1 Thanks for the tip... but would you mind providing the **bnb/exit** function, too?  I put this code in my init.el, and now I can't exit without calling **bnb/really-kill-emacs** because it says "Symbol's function definition is void: bnb/exit".  Sorry, I'm new to emacs and couldn't figure out how to write the function in question.