# How to use one instance of emacs as the default text editor? [Linux]

Tags: linux, emacs, ubuntu

**What I would like to achieve**

- one instance of emacs
- if i open any text file from nautilus, it should open in the current emacs instance
- if i close emacs, it shouldn't really close it, just hide it

**What I have currently**

- I set emacs23 to start at startup
- I have (start-server) in my init
- I leave emacs open
- I have emacsclient as the default texteditor

**Issues I encountered while trying to achieve what I wanted**

- emacs gives the following error if i quit emacs and try to start it again

> File error: Cannot bind server socket, address already in use

**Things I tried**

- [emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon)
- [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001485/how-do-i-keep-emacs-server-running-when-the-current-window-is-closed-x-on-windo)
- [emacs fu](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2009/03/windows-and-daemons.html)

Update: I tried again with the stackoverflow link, and now most of it is working.
However, something I would like to be able to do is to reload the init file, so that I can make changes to my init file without restarting the computer. Any ideas?

Also, if the server is running and I have emacs false-closed (see emacs fu link), how can i start it again without loading a file? eg what would the equivalent of running emacs23 be, as this doesn't work (see error written above)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

- remove `(start-server)` from `.emacs`
- use `emacsclient "$@" -a ""` to start emacs whether it is running or not

If you save `emacsclient "$@" -a ""` as a script e.g. in `editor` file then `editor -c` creates a new frame, `editor -t` opens new frame in the terminal, and `editor FILE` visits `FILE` in an existing frame. It starts emacs server if it is not running.

Comment: i wish I could upvote you 1000 times. this was the info I needed to get this working on OSX. thanks much

Comment: I get an error message with your script: "-a or ALTERNATIVE_EDITOR can not be an empty string." on windows.

Comment: @progician: [empty string is explicitly supported](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/emacsclient-Options.html#emacsclient-Options). If it doesn't work on Windows; try to set `ALTERNATE_EDITOR=emacs --daemon` environment variable (drop `-a ""` from the command). If it doesn't work; [ask a separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (this question is about Linux, though the solution works as is on OSX too)

Answer (score 3):

I start emacs with `emacs --daemon` so that emacs starts in a daemonized mode. Then I would set EDITOR to `emacsclient -t -a emacs -nw` which opens a new terminal emacs frame attached to your emacs daemon, with a "no window" version of emacs used as an alternate if there isn't an emacs-server running. For opening emacs windows in the GUI I the editor command is `emacsclient -n -c -a emacs`.

It's also possible to run more than one emacs instance on a single machine, if you don't want to have buffers from one project be intermingled with buffers from another project. See my [my post](http://criticalfutures.com/2010/10/running-multiple-emacs-daemons-on-a-single-system/) on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

> However, something I would like to be
>   able to do is to reload the init file,
>   so that I can make changes to my init
>   file without restarting the computer.

Reading through the methods behind the daemon-effect you're looking for, none of them seem to preclude simply loading your init file and issuing an `eval-buffer` call after edits are made.

> Also, if the server is running and I
>   have emacs false-closed (see emacs fu
>   link), how can i start it again
>   without loading a file?

Running `emacsclient` (rather than `emacs23`) should do the trick, I would think.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, not sure about running emacs as a client, but I frequently revise and apply changes to my .emacs file, without closing emacs.

Simple edit the file (within or outside of emacs, it doesn't matter which).  The M-x load-file, emacs will ask you for the file's path and name, which is easy if it's ~/.emacs.

Type the path and filename then RET and emacs will reload with your changes.  Any buffers you had open will still be there.