# .bash_profile function to open emacs

Tags: macos, bash, function, emacs, terminal

i want to open a file in emacs, regardless of whether or not it already exists.

```
function emacs() {
    touch $1
    open -a Emacs.app $1
}
```

it only opens the file if it already exists. if i try a file that doesn't exist, i get the error:

The file /Users/danfithian/Desktop/Code/Euler/problem18.cpp does not exist.

Comment: Does the directory structure you're passing in exist? `touch` can't create new directories

Comment: What version of `bash` are you running? Mine doesn't have a `-a` option for `open`. And I'm curious why this is necessary, since `emacs` will "open" a non-existent file name and let you write it, but if you change your mind you can exit and the file you decided not to create won't be there.

Comment: @mbratch `-a` flag is OS X specific. [`open`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html)

Comment: The 'touch $1' should solve your problem. What is the question? If the problem is that there are missing directory(s) in the $1 path, then you might look for a version of mkdirp that will create the whole path of dirs; here's one I use http://pastebin.com/aBWJGwwK

Comment: unrelated issue, you should change `$1` to `"$1"` to avoid problems with spaces and such in the path

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably missing something, but why not just use `emacs $1` (or the equivalent `emacsclient` call)? Isn't that sufficient? Emacs will create a new-file buffer if the file does not yet exist.

Comment: The problem is that if you invoke 'open -a Emacs.app $1' on osx, it fails when the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Why use `-a`? That's the question.

Comment: On OSX the -a option:  -a application
         Specifies the application to use for opening the file

Comment: Still not clear to me. Why use `-a` here? What do you hope to gain by it? Why do you think it is needed/desirable here? And what happens if you do ***not*** use `-a` here --- doesn't it work?

Comment: Here's the 'man open' for OSX http://pastebin.com/WTv8m6Bx So he's using -a cause he knows he wants to open the file with Emacs.app. Does that make sense?

Comment: My suggestion was to not use `open` at all but just use `emacs`.  Why go through `open`, telling it what program to use, instead of just specifying that program at the outset, to the shell? (And I don't see why `touch` would then be needed either.) What am I missing? What is the point of this `emacs` function, if it is not to just run the `emacs` executable on the given file?

Comment: I wasn't commenting on your suggestion either way. I was simply responding to the OPs post and your question as to why he was using -a. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. My comment asking why `-a` was not too clear. I meant to ask why use `open...` at all.

Comment: @Drew `open` spawns a new instance if one is needed, and doesn't if one is already running, so it's very much like `emacs` and `emacsclient` with the bonus of not having to think about which one you want. The downside is it doesn't deal well with non-existant files, which is what the script in question is trying to work around.

Comment: @cobbal: I see; thanks. For that use case -- use `emacsclient` or if no Emacs running then use `emacs` -- there are other solutions. People have been using scripts or aliases to do that since way back when there was only `gnuserv` and `gnuclient`. I'm no expert, but I would expect that `emacsclient` itself might even provide a solution/answer for that simple use case now... Just checking the doc quickly I see that `emacsclient` has option `-a` that does this. It starts Emacs in daemon mode if its arg is "". Does this not satisfy the requirement?

Comment: @Drew well that is interesting. I saw that option, but it never occurred to me to use it for launching Emacs (man pages I have installed just mention "alternate editor"). Unfortunately, the `""` arg doesn't seem to play well with the default emacs that is installed in OS X. I'll play around with a few more things and see if I can get it working.

Comment: I'm no expert on this, but I think the daemon should be your friend here. If "" does not do what you expect/want, consider whether you think there might be an Emacs bug (and report it, if so: `M-x report-emacs-bug`) -- dunno.

Answer (score 0):

See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171280/how-to-launch-gui-emacs-from-command-line-in-osx) on Stack overflow. The suggestion there is to call the application directly `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs "$1"` rather than through open