# can't make an alias on mac terminal to open emacs on a new window

Tags: macos, emacs

I have just taken a C programming course. The computers we used in class were set up such that by typing the command:    `emacs filename.c`the linux terminal would open a new emacs window on the desktop.
Now I have a Mac and tried to make an alias to achieve the same by typing the following command in the terminal:

```
alias emacs="/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs "$@""
```

I found that on an older question ([How to launch GUI Emacs from command line in OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171280/how-to-launch-gui-emacs-from-command-line-in-osx)). The command works but after closing the terminal and then re opening it if I type `emacs filename.c` it does not work anymore. So is there a way to create the alias permanently?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding it to your profile:

```
echo 'alias emacs="/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs "$@""' >> ~/.profile
```

The file ~/.profile is run when you log in, so that alias will be automatically created each time you log in.