# How to return focus to terminal after closing GUI emacsclient on mac OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line, emacs

I've followed the advice laid out in [How to launch GUI Emacs from command line in OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171280/how-to-launch-gui-emacs-from-command-line-in-osx) and on the Emacs for mac osx [how-to page](https://emacsformacosx.com/tips) to setup my GUI emacs so that it grabs focus on startup.

When I run an `emacs` standalone session, emacs GUI properly grabs focus and focus is returned to my terminal upon killing my emacs frame.

However, killing my `emacsclient` frame (aliased to this [script](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/caldwell/5026506/raw/fba22db3e6aa21fdda8b2db366c6db90e628dff4/ec)) with `C-x C-c` does not return focus to the terminal.

Is there a good way to do this?

**update**
`M-x kill-emacs` does return focus to terminal. So the issue is killing that emacsclient frame specifically.

Comment: You may need an applescript to achieve your goal.

Comment: My special issue is similar. I have configured my git to use external editor for commit message. After I have closed the editor the terminal (iTerm) is getting back the focus.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by running an Applescript to 1) note the current application, 2) launch Emacs and wait, and 3) return focus to the then-current application. It looks like:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set frontApp to (path to frontmost application as Unicode text)
end tell

do shell script "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient -c"

activate application frontApp
```

Comment: In the intervening year, somebody implemented [mac-pseudo-daemon](https://melpa.org/#/mac-pseudo-daemon) which uses emacs hooks to call Applescript to hide the emacs window when a graphical frame is closed. Much easier!