# How to fix the "Unknown option '-a'" message when using Emacs to edit git commit messages?

Tags: git, emacs, configuration

I set Emacs as the commit message editor. After running 'git commit', Emacs window pops up with "Unknown option '-a'" in the mini-buffer while having no content in the main buffer window.

At the same time, the command-line displays

```
git commit
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... 2021-06-27 16:43:16.143 Emacs-x86_64-10_14[8977:3205755] Failed to initialize color list unarchiver: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: non-keyed archive cannot be decoded by NSKeyedUnarchiver" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: non-keyed archive cannot be decoded by NSKeyedUnarchiver}
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: May you share the config where emac is set? Or maybe the command used to set it?

Comment: Given the Objective-C stuff in the message, you must be using OS X Emacs; see [How to launch GUI Emacs from command line in OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10171280/1256452)

Comment: "I set Emacs as the commit message editor" is probably the source of your problem.  Please *show* exactly how you did that.